# how to do this math problem

Tags: functional-analysis

Let A be a closed subset of a normed space E, and let x belongs to E. Show that if A is (sequentially) compact then a best approximation of x exists in A. Conclude that if E is finite-dimensional then there is a best approximation of x in A even if A is not compact. How to start?

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title.  What have you done on this problem?  Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: If you are advanced enough to type all the words to the problem you are advanced enough to discuss an idea of what the terms mean and some preliminary ideas as to what they may imply.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u =\inf_{v\in A} ||x-v||. $ Then there exists $(v_n) \subset A $ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty } ||v_n -x | =u .$ But we can also assume that $v_n \to h\in A .$ Thus $u =||x-h ||$ for some $h.$

Comment: In finite dimensional space the closed ball is compact. Thus we can replace the set $A$ by $B(x, u+1 ) \cap A $ where $B(x, u+1)$ is closed ball with center at $x$ and radius equal to $u+1,$